# Changes made in the Xhtml formed from xml and XSLT need to be reflected back in he XML

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, xslt, xhtml

I have an XML file that I've transformed with xsl and loaded into a browser as html. That html is made editable using content editable attribute of html5. When they're done I need to transform their html edits back to the original xml document.
The changes may even include adding new nodes to existing ones.
Any ideas how to do it.
Thanking you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously some transformations aren't reversible. If the XML contains a list of transactions, and the HTML contains the total value, and the user changes the total, you aren't going to be able to use that information to update the original list. So mapping the new values back cannot be an automatic process.

My preferred approach would be to use XForms: generate your output as XForms, including bindings back to an XML model so that updates to the form are reflected back in the model. Anything else you do is essentially re-inventing this technology.

Comment: I want to use style sheets as i require dynamically to change the UI . I am actually trying to make a WYSIWYG editor one like XOPUS. Thank you for this approach but i want other approaches like ajax or from javascript . Can you suggest me other methods. And i love the XOPUS editor which is completely done using javascript.

Comment: And upto my knowledge i think Xfprms has no complete browser support. Atleast i need IE,CHROME and FirefOX